# C# - Winforms controls inheriting odd styling

Tags: c#, winforms, button, padding, styling

I have a  project in which I am using tableLayoutPanles to organize the controls in user controls. In design time everything looks fine, but as soon I run the application, the styling goes crazy. The padding on the buttons become ridiculously big.
As soon as I programatically in run time move the usercontrol to another form (change its parrent), it goes normal.

I suposse that I might have set some stupid property in the first form to force it to inherit the syling. I check a lot of stuff and could not find some.

Anyone got some pointers on what it might be?

Comment: Is it an anchoring issue? Are the buttons anchhored on all 4 corners and when you open the form the first time, it's stretched because the button is anchored on all 4 sides and so is pulled in all directions?

Comment: Post repro code. You'll find it in the `.Designer` file for your form.

Comment: The buttons are in an flowlayoutControl whish is docked to fill in a cell of a tableLayoutPanel and spans accrtoss several cells. in a single row.

Comment: The funny thing is that that whole rows height is also increasing although I've set the height at a fixed number of pixels.

Since the buttons are in a flowlayoutpannel, they should not strech